# Issue in navigation

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

Hi every i have made an application and i run in simulator and iphone its works fine and i alnalize it and remove memory leakages.

But today i ran the app on simulator when i am going to second view it display the view fine but when i came back to second view it crash without showing any message ...

Is it bad Excess? i don't think soo...

Comment: Post some code and crash log so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: Yes it is bad Excess,but without any code we cant say where it present.

Comment: There is nothing shown in the crash log its just blank...

Comment: Hi every i have made an application and i run in simulator and iphone its works fine and i alnalize it and remove memory leakages.

But today i ran the app on simulator when i am going to second view it display the view fine but when i came back to First view it crash without showing any message ...

Is it bad Excess? i don't think soo...

Comment: show your dealloc method

Comment: If no stacktrace is shown in your log it's better to build & debug your application - instead of build & run. When you debug and it crashes, at the right side of the debugging tools (step over, step into, etc) is the "stacktrace" of the given thread, using this dropdown selection will show you where your code crashed exactly. Also at the bottom of the editor will be the crash reason (SIG_ABRT, Bad Access, SIG_KILL, etc)

Comment: - (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
 [appDelegate release];
 [staticImageDictionary release];
 [siteData release];
 [newdata release];
 [connection release];
 [webData release];
 
 [activity release];

}

Comment: `
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
 [appDelegate release];
 [staticImageDictionary release];
 [siteData release];
 [newdata release];
 [connection release];
 [webData release];
 
 [activity release];

}
`

Comment: @ tsakoyan very very thanks man i have sort it out .....:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then try this

dont release appDelegate object here.it is shared copy for whole app. release all object before super dealloc.

```
- (void)dealloc {  
//[appDelegate release];//here crash 
[staticImageDictionary release];
 [siteData release]; 
[newdata release]; 
[connection release]; 
[webData release];
 [activity release]; 
[super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are releasing the viewcontroller that has delegate for MKMapView, do not release the viewController that has MKMapView delegates. I think you released that delegate when you were fixing the memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C, It generally  happens that when you realese object in dealloc method which is already "release", it will display bad excess.  To track which object is already release use [NSZombieEnabled](http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) You can see more clarification in your console.